# What is the best way of searching through email via Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, email, authentication

I have implemented three legged auth to gmail using the Zend framework. I am wondering what the best way of finding emails once authenticated is (for example by a mix of title regex, sender, date range) - which is efficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with indexing it into DB and then use any search you would seem fit (WHERE, LIKE, FULLTEXT).

Comment: I am looking to only add items to the DB that match certain email addresses - is there a way to do that? Or do I have to copy everything and only then parse the emails I'm interested in?

Comment: I'd insert everything. Search/filter/delete would be much faster :) Buit only if the number of emails is in reasonable range like... at most hundreds...